# Error when running hyperparameter tuning job with SageMaker locally

Tags: runtime-error, local, amazon-sagemaker

I was trying to run a Hyperparameter tuning job locally in my machine using a sample code as given below.

```
tuner = HyperparameterTuner(estimator,
objective_metric_name,
hyperparameter_ranges,
metric_definitions,
max_jobs=4,
max_parallel_jobs=2,
objective_type=objective_type,
base_tuning_job_name="hpo-tuning-demo"
)

tuner.fit(inputs=channels)
```

This gives an error: `AttributeError: 'LocalSagemakerClient' object has no attribute 'create_hyper_parameter_tuning_job'`. Updating SageMaker and boto3 as suggested in some other posts didn't help.

Does this mean hyperparameter tuning locally is not supported, or if I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, hyperparameters tuning is not supported locally as HPO library is not available in the SageMaker SDK.

Comment: It would be nice if you include an explanation or some resources why it's not supported. Doing this increases the probability that people like your answer and vote it up. Please see [answer] and edit your answer.